# Jhipster microservice app freezing on start in docker container

Tags: docker, jhipster

we build Jhipster microservice into Docker container on VM in AWS, building completed with no errors, when application starts we see the following in console:
[screenshot from console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nqLg.png)

And nothing happens, no errors or warnings, any idea where we should start investigate it?

Comment: Which service discovery do you use?

Comment: We use Jhispter Registry, issue that we already found that when we build with -Prod it uses external git repo for configuration, by default it's not available from our network.